# Behaviour of llvm basic types in the MSVC IDE

Tags: c++, debugging, llvm-c++-api

I've faced some unexplainable behaviour of the built-in MSVC debugger. It looks like program being debugged and debugger itself are operating on different sets of variables. This variable (arg) have type llvm::StringRef. This class has two data members - char* Data and size_t Length.

Its implicit conversion constructor from std::string is trivial:

```
StringRef(const std::string &Str)
: Data(Str.data()), Length(Str.length()) 
{}
```

Hovewer, result of this conversion looks like bloody mess in the local variables tab of the debugger. When i try to take mini-dump of this object and add watch (long long*)(&arg) it looks pretty much the same. ***BUT*** the result of execution of this piece is ok, as seen in the console window.

[image: debugging session - loval variables]
[image: debugging session - watches]

Comment: You should use `c_str` not `.data`, i am not sure if `.data` in MSDN is null terminated and you might be seeing undefined behavior.

Comment: Also you need a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It is not my code. I'm working with large and mature open-source framework (LLVM). They tend to avoid heap allocations for temporary objects by using classes like this one.

Comment: Minimal Complete verifiable example is trivial. The StringRef class is taken from LLVM repository.

void test1(StringRef arg)
{
  outs() << arg;
  outs().flush();
}

int main()
{
  std::string q = "BoZo";
  test1(q);
}

Comment: Do you compile with MSVC? What settings? I've tried it on my MSVC2013 and it works fine.

Comment: msvc 2015, X64 Debug build. Other stuff is default.

Comment: Latest LLVM release require a C++14 - ready compiler. That's why i had to use a new MSVC.